# How to redirect traffic for 404 error to a different url when using a Cloud Run service to proxy a GCS bucket?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, proxy, reverse-proxy, google-cloud-run

Currently I am using Cloud Run service to proxy a GCS bucket. Used the following https://github.com/domZippilli/gcs-proxy-cloud-run to use as a proxy. Now I want to redirect the traffic for 404(Not found in bucket) to a different url to show the help pages. As I don't have any go land expertise, can anyone suggest how to redirect traffic to a different url for getting a 404 from a cloud storage bucket through the proxy code in the go lang?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle redirecting 404s to static help pages, is to configure the "specialty pages" at the Cloud Storage bucket level. This means creating, for example, a page called `not-found.html` and uploading it to the bucket. Then configuring the bucket so that when a resource isn't found, the page `not-found.html` is returned to the user instead. This works at the Cloud Storage level, so it's independent of any load balancers or proxies.

To configure this, find your backend bucket in the console, and select "Edit website configuration" from the more options menu (three vertical dots.) Then add the relative path to your "not found" page as the error page.

See more here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages